# Vue nuxt npm run dev new img not found

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hi i add image to assets folder after run `npm run dev` in my page can't show image
[image]

this my code

```
<div
    :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImagePath})`,
              backgroundPosition: 'center',
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'cover' }"
  >

import backgroundImagePath from '@/assets/img/bg/red2.jpg'

export default {
  components: {
    Navbar, Slider, Login, Footer
  },
  data () {
    return { backgroundImagePath }
  }
}
```

but, i change to old image `import backgroundImagePath from '@/assets/img/bg/red1.jpg'`
it work
[image]

I'm check in folder for sure it has both image

folder tree

```
--assets
  --bg
    --red1.jpg add before npm run dev
    --red2.jpg add after npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try restart IIS, So it working but i don't know why